# How to get image size after changing src attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery to change the image source with

```
var img = $("#image-holder img")
img.attr("src","uploads/image.jpg");
```

At this point, how can I get the `clientWidth` and height of the image? I've tried different approaches like

```
img.width()
img.clientWidth
img.width
```

but some of them don't work and others simply return 0.

Do you have any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: note that "The Element.clientWidth property is zero for inline elements and elements with no CSS; "
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientWidth

Comment: thanks @FelDev I didn't know that. Do you think I could change something (I don't know, add some css) to make that work with the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use load event for getting image width.

I create a sample for before and after loading image.

```
var img = $("#image-holder img");
img.attr("src","https://www.w3schools.com/images/compatible_chrome.gif");
console.log('before load: ' + img.width());

var load = function(e){

   console.log('after load: ' + e.width);
};
```

```js
var img = $("#image-holder img");
img.attr("src","https://www.w3schools.com/images/compatible_chrome.gif");
console.log('before load: ' + img.width());

var load = function(e){
   //alert(e.width);
   console.log('after load: ' + e.width);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="image-holder">
  <img src="" onload="load(this)"/>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to wait until your image finished loading to get it's size.

```
var img = $("#image-holder img")
$("#image-holder img").load(function() {
  console.log(img.width);
});
img.attr("src","uploads/image.jpg");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am getting a weird `TypeError: e.indexOf is not a function | jquery.min.js:2:82466`

Comment: I must confess I'm not too familar with the jquery syntax - what does `$("#image-holder img")` refer to? Can you add the html code to your question too?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to wait for the image to complete loading.

You can bind a load() method to the new Image to achieve this.

HTML:

```
<div id="image-holder">
    <!-- A 150x150 blue square -->
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF" />
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
// Function to load/ update the original image.
let loadImg = function(newSize) {

    // Grab a pointer to the current image
    let newImg = $("#image-holder > img")

    // Update the source to the new URL
    // This image will be of the requested size and red
    newImg.attr("src",'https://via.placeholder.com/'+newSize+'/ff0000');

    // Bind a load handler (might as well add an error handler also)
    newImg.bind({
        load: function() {
            alert('The new image is: '+newImg.width()+'x'+newImg.height());
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('There was an error loading the new image.');
        }
    });

};

// Load the new image (with a set size)...
loadImg(350);
```

Working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/jjjjssssfidd/wpc3oxk0/4/